# Type Casting a Column to bigint in Padrino Active Record

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord, padrino

I have upgraded to the latest Ruby on a Padrino application and I am having errors with active record when creating a new object. It's validating a number (an ISBN) as 4 bytes. The error is:

`9781407005416 is out of range for ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with limit 4`

How do I tell a Ruby active record class to use 8 byte limit?

I am not talking about running a migration, the table is already `bigint(20)`.

I thought the following would work:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    attribute :isbn, :integer, :limit => 8
end
```

I then get errors on `find_by` and `as_json` for the ISBN field:

`#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'type_cast_for_database' for :integer:Symbol`

I turned the 'isbn' method into a new instance variable instead of changing the column of the attribute created by the active record adapter.

I know the [column has a limit](http://technology.customink.com/blog/2015/01/06/activerecord-42s-type-casting/), but not sure how to access the type of the column to update it.

Falling a solution to the type setting is there a way to skip the validation that is now happening in the active record `ensure_in_range`.

Is there a way to change the built in `DEFAULT_LIMIT = 4` of `class Integer < Value` from my app? This is related to the [following changes in Ruby](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/28007) but I have no access to changing the Padrino source.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MySQL, the ruby adapter is not capturing the big int and adjusting the limit accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I tell a Ruby active record class to use 8 byte limit?
>   AFAIK, AR should figure this out directly from the database metadata.

First, restart the app if not done already - column types are cached.  Next, I would verify that AR actually sees the column as you expect. Try this to make sure it is doing what you think:

```
p Book.columns.select{ |col| col.name == 'isbn'}
```

Look at the @range and @limit under @cast_type.

> I turned the 'isbn' method into a new instance variable instead of
>   changing the column of the attribute created by the active record
>   adapter.

Does this mean that you overrode the isbn getter?  If so, what exactly does that code look like?

Comment: @Conor - glad to help.  What was the result of 
"p Book.columns.select{ |col| col.name == 'isbn'}" ?
I tested this with the mysql2 driver (mysql2-0.4.5) on Rails 4.2.8 and it correctly interprets the field as a bigint and handles the value you have above.  The post you referenced is about sqllite which has problems with this and might require the "attribute :upc, Type ..." hack, but MySQL should not.   Since this is an internal API it should be avoided IMHO.  Are you by any chance using the mysql1 driver or an old mysql2 driver?

Comment: I would love to avoid it, but getting errors with it anyway. Seems the problem is deeper as the output is correct "[#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractMysqlAdapter::Column:0x007fbb930f95a0 @strict=true, @collation=nil, @extra="", @name="isbn", @cast_type=#<ActiveRecord::Type::Integer:0x007fbb92d01c40 @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @limit=8, @range=-9223372036854775808...9223372036854775808>, @sql_type="bigint(20)", @null=true, @default=nil, @default_function=nil>]
". Using mysql2 0.4.7, but not Rails, Sinatra 2.0.0 and padrino 0.14.1.1.

Comment: Getting rid of the protected_attributes gem as it's time it goes, with let you know what happens.

Comment: Passing the test with active record 5.1.2, will deploy it and see how it goes live.

Comment: @Conor, looking at the source code of Padrino, it relies on sequel which in turn requires activerecord.   Looks like sequel stacks a *lot* on top of it so I suspect that the error lies somewhere in there.  If that is the case, we may have to go with your first approach (attribute :isbn, :integer ...).

Comment: I concur. I am trying to update as much as possible the active record gem, in hopes that the bug was addressed. But there so many changes between 4 and 5 (having issued duplicating a where query in 5 "      second_query = main_query.includes(:book_author).references(:book_author).uniq
"), that I might have to solve it with the (attribute :isbn, :integer).

Comment: @Conor, if you do have to go with the "attribute :isbn..." thing let me know and I will add it to the answer.

Comment: Did up end using it. But as you mention it's just a hack to get over issues. Should not be the official answer as it's likely not an issue in active record 5.

Comment: AR 4 seemed to handle it fine when I tested without Padrino.  I suspect the problem is in Padrino or Sequel.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
validates_inclusion_of :isbn, in: 1..4294967296
```

(That's 2^32, ie maximum 4 byte integer.)

Or for 8 bytes, try:

```
validates_inclusion_of :isbn, in: 1..1.8446744e+19
```

To confirm this very large range is valid:

```
> 1e10.in?(1..1.8446744e+19)
true
> 1e20.in?(1..1.8446744e+19)
false
```

(I'm assuming AR for Padrino works like in Rails.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately the validation is added on top of the check for the byte limit, so it does not override the default limit of 4 bytes.